# JSF - rich:componentControl and a4j:jsFunction redirect issue

Tags: jsf, redirect, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have two questions in one. First off all, I don't understand how to use the rich:componentControl, I used an old code and this website: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces33-4xMigrationGuideUnleashed but I still have this error whatever I try:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /admin.xhtml @191,30  Parent not an instance of ClientBehaviorHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText@1ee71d84
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:521)
>     com.lesim.fst.service.FilterUTF8.doFilter(FilterUTF8.java:20)

There is my code:

```
<rich:column>
  <h:outputText value="#{msg.la8}" id="actionId" >
    <rich:componentControl event="onmouseover" target="menu" operation="show" />
  </h:outputText>
  <rich:contextMenu id="menu" mode="client">
    <rich:menuItem label="#{msg.ll8}" onclick="functionEdit();" icon="/images/edit16.png" />
    <rich:menuItem label="#{msg.ll9}" onclick="functionSuppr();" icon="/images/supprimer16.png" />
  </rich:contextMenu>
  <a4j:jsFunction name="functionEdit" action="#{administrateurBean.editAdministrateur()}" >
    <a4j:param value="#{administrateur.idadministrateur}" name="idadministrateur" />
  </a4j:jsFunction>
  <a4j:jsFunction name="functionSuppr" action="#{administrateurBean.deleteAdministrateur()}">
    <a4j:param value="#{administrateur.idadministrateur}" name="idadministrateur" />
  </a4j:jsFunction>
</rich:column>
```

My goal is to show the rich:contextMenu when the h:outputText is onmouseover, and the rich:componentControl is needed because the onmouseover attribute don't work for rich:contextMenu (according to this website : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-7497 )

You can also see that I don't directly use my Bean methodes, I put them in an a4j:jsFunction. It is because the action attribute don't work for rich:menuItem (according to this website: *[Oh no... I can't give this one... I thought you were asking to give a maximum of my own search but apparently you don't want it so much... ]* )
So I used his solution, but the redirection from the faces-config doesn't work

faces-config:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <display-name>admin.xhtml</display-name>
  <from-view-id>/admin.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{administrateurBean.editAdministrateur}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>edit</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/editAdministrateur.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{administrateurBean.deleteAdministrateur}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>list</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

If someone sees a way to fix one of my problems, or both, you're welcome

Thanks,
Quentin

Comment: The website I hadn't post:
http://www.kianworknotes.com/2012/12/richmenuitems-action-not-working-in.html

Comment: Thanks,
I accept the example because I don't really see were I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says h:outputText is not a behavior holder component (in particular this component does not trigger 'mouseover' event).

Refer to the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/

You can use for example `h:outputLabel` instead (note that event name is `mouseover`)

```
  <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.la8}" id="actionId">
    <rich:componentControl event="mouseover" target="menu" operation="show"/>
  </h:outputLabel>
```

Or this way using `onmouseover` attribute:

```
   <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.la8}" id="actionId"
                  onmouseover="${rich:component('menu')}.show()"/>
```